# Why there is no 'writable' and 'value' in the property of document.location.host

Tags: javascript, document

I use `Object.freeze(document.location)` to freeze the document.location, but I find that I still can change document.location.host. And I find that there is not `writable` in the property of `document.location.host`, is this the reason why I can do that?

```
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(document.location)
// result
{replace: {…}, href: {…}, ancestorOrigins: {…}, origin: {…}, protocol: {…}, …}
ancestorOrigins: {get: ƒ, set: undefined, enumerable: true, configurable: false}
assign: {value: ƒ, writable: false, enumerable: true, configurable: false}
hash: {get: ƒ, set: ƒ, enumerable: true, configurable: false}
host:
configurable: false
enumerable: true
get: ƒ host()
set: ƒ host()
__proto__: Object
hostname: {get: ƒ, set: ƒ, enumerable: true, configurable: false}
href:
configurable: false
enumerable: true
value: "https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-CN/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty"
writable: false
__proto__: Object
origin: {get: ƒ, set: undefined, enumerable: true, configurable: false}
pathname: {get: ƒ, set: ƒ, enumerable: true, configurable: false}
port: {get: ƒ, set: ƒ, enumerable: true, configurable: false}
protocol: {get: ƒ, set: ƒ, enumerable: true, configurable: false}
reload: {value: ƒ, writable: false, enumerable: true, configurable: false}
replace: {value: ƒ, writable: false, enumerable: true, configurable: false}
search: {get: ƒ, set: ƒ, enumerable: true, configurable: false}
toString: {value: ƒ, writable: false, enumerable: true, configurable: false}
valueOf: {value: ƒ, writable: false, enumerable: false, configurable: false}
Symbol(Symbol.toPrimitive): {value: undefined, writable: false, enumerable: false, configurable: false}
__proto__: Object
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because `host` is a setter/getter, not a plain property. Were it a plain property, and you used `Object.freeze` on it, it could not be modified:

```js
const obj = { foo: 'foo' };
Object.freeze(obj);
obj.foo = 'newval';
console.log(obj.foo);
```

But when you assign to a setter, you *do not actually change the property there*, so `Object.freeze` does not prevent you from calling the setter:

```js
const obj = {
  set foo(newVal) {
    console.log('set foo called');
  },
  get foo() {
    console.log('get foo called');
    return 'getVal';
  }
};
Object.freeze(obj);
obj.foo = 'newval';
console.log(obj.foo);
```

The `writable` and `value` attributes only exist for *data descriptors*, which exclude setters/getters. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptor):

> **value**
>
> The value associated with the property **(data descriptors only)**.
>
> **writable**
>
> true if and only if the value associated with the property may be changed **(data descriptors only).**